# cleos create account error with Chain API plugin is not enabled

Tags: accounts, create

I just started set up my eos dev environment.  I started my node as

> ./nodeos  --config-dir config --data-dir data --enable-stale-production --producer-name eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin

And start my keosd as:

> ./keosd  --data-dir data --http-server-address lochost:8899

I can use cleos to add keys, list keys etc. However when I try to create account:

> ./cleos  -u http://localhost:8899 create account eosio  user xxxx xxxx

I see error such as

> Error 3110001: Missing Chain API Plugin
>
> Ensure that you have eosio::chain_api_plugin added to your node's configuration!
>
> Error Details:
>   Chain API plugin is not enabled"

But I clear has eosio::chain_api_plugin enabled in my nodeos.

Comment: Same issue here, looking for an answer.

Comment: What I did was run nodeos only  without running keosd. You can create account by

"./cleos create account eosio user xxx"

Answer (score 2):

As I can not comment yet due to the low reputation as I made the account recently, I have some queries related to your problem.

1. You are running cleos command at port 8899 whereas you did not mention the port 8899 while starting the blockchain. It might have set the default port 8888 which might be the reason of failing this command.
2. ./keosd --data-dir data --http-server-address **lochost:8899** ---> is it typo? Because it should be localhost:8899.

HTH.